# Azure site recovery + databases

Tags: azure, disaster-recovery

We've got a Atlassian Bitbucket Datacentre installation which we want to DR to another region.

Can Azure Site Recovery be used to replicate the PostgreSQL server? 
Can Azure Site Recovery be used to replicate the NFS server?
Can Azure Site Recovery be used to replicate a VM from a VMSS?

It would be great if we could orchestrate the whole thing with ASR as it would make PITR a breeze. If not we'd need to look at each item individually then work out how to coordinate the retores to the same point in time.

Thanks
Phill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a generic question and I would need more detailed idea about your Infrastructure. But yes you can use ASR to replicate these servers. ASR is a mechanism that installs an agent on the source machine and this agent replicates all the data to PS and eventually uploaded to Azure.

However it isn't application aware which means it won't give you PITR for DBs, but you will have an option to failover (restore) entire machine even 5 minutes ago. Since ASR creates recovery point every 5 minutes. It isn't a file level replication but a server level replication. Below article implies for Vmware and Physical machines replication to Azure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/vmware-azure-architecture

Let me know if this helps.